# Parse nested json with a proxy in a Sencha Touch 2 store using rootProperty

Tags: json, nested, sencha-touch-2, store, sencha-architect

I have a JSON response that is nested like the following (simplified, but same format):

```
{
    "response":{
        "v":"1.0",
        "users":[
            {
            "firstName":"Nicole",
            "LastName":"A",
            },
            {
            "firstName":"John",
            "LastName":"B",
            },
            {
            "firstName":"Bob",
            "LastName":"C",
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Here is the model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Field'
    ],

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'firstName'
            },
            {
                name: 'lastName'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

I am starting from the sencha architect tutorial for CityBars, so most of the code should be quite basic, and I am just trying to get the users from the json response loaded.  Here is the controller:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    launch: function() {
                var me = this;
                Ext.Viewport.setMasked({ message: 'Loading Attendees...' });
                me.getUsers(function (store) {
                me.getDataList().setStore(store);
              });
    },

    getUsers: function(callback) {
            var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('UserStore'),
            url = 'http://urltogetjsonresponse'
            store.getProxy().setUrl(url);
            store.load(function() {
                            callback(store);
                          });
    },
});
```

Here is the store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.UserStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.User',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    config: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.User',
        storeId: 'UserStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'response.user'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I tried 'response.user' but it did not work for me. I have already looked all over and know that using rootProperty: 'user' would work, if the users attribute were at the same level as "response" instead of nested under it. I have also tried adding record: 'users' but that did not seem to work either.

If anybody knows if this is doable and has an easy solution to this, that would be great. I don't actually understand how the proxy works, so if anybody can explain a bit about that, it would be helpful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Sencha's documentation about the JSON reader :

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "ok": true,
    "msg": "Users found",
    "users": [{
        "userId": 123,
        "name": "Ed Spencer",
        "email": "ed@sencha.com"
    }],
    "metaData": {
        "idProperty": 'userId',
        "rootProperty": "users",
        "totalProperty": 'count',
        "successProperty": 'ok',
        "messageProperty": 'msg'
    }
}
```

The `rootProperty` here is 'users', so you'll need to specify `users` (which is the name of the array containing your instances of model) and not `user` .